# jQuery toggleClass with conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

Does anyone know how to write the following in a neater, one line format? I'm sure it's possible but can't get very far with it.

```
if($('#myDiv').hasClass('hidden')){
   $('#myDiv').toggleClass('shown hidden');
}
```

Basically to only perform a toggle in one direction.

Many thanks,

Tom.

Comment: you want this in one line/.... it means

Comment: var result = $("#myDiv").hasClass("hidden") ? $('#myDiv').toggleClass('shown hidden') : false

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('#myDiv.hidden').toggleClass('shown hidden');
```

Comment: @FelixKling: The selector guarantees that hidden is set, I think.

Comment: My apologies... (deleted my comment).

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupidly simple.  Thanks so much for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just call `$('#myDiv').removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown')` (and the corresponding inverse). It'll remove `.hidden` if it's there, and add `.shown` if it doesn't have it yet.

Comment: I take it that the idea is that the two classes shouldn't be assigned at the same time, and no other logic is dependent on the conditional. If the OP wants it in one line, it's a valid assumption. Don't know why, but hey.

Comment: `.toggle` is much simpler